# how to take a screenshot of a PySide widget that is a window, and include the titlebar and border

Tags: python, screenshot, pyside

I figured out how to take a screen capture of a widget in PySide QT, but it doesn't include nonclient areas e.g. the titlebar and border.

```
def screenCaptureWidget(widget, filename, fileformat='png'):
    pixmap =  QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(widget)
    pixmap.save(filename, fileformat)
```

Two questions:

- how do I include the nonclient areas?
- how do I get the geometry of the window rectangle relative to its client area (0,0) point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer to both questions, after finding `QWidget.geometry()` and [`QWidget.frameGeometry()`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.frameGeometry), which give screen coordinates (as a QRect) of the client and nonclient areas, respectively.

```
def getRelativeFrameGeometry(widget):
    g = widget.geometry()
    fg = widget.frameGeometry()
    return fg.translated(-g.left(),-g.top())

def screenCaptureWidget(widget, filename, fileformat='png'):
    rfg = getRelativeFrameGeometry(widget)
    pixmap =  QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId(),
                                       rfg.left(), rfg.top(),
                                       rfg.width(), rfg.height())
    pixmap.save(filename, fileformat)
```